# Windows Phone 7 Jquery Mobile: Keypress/Keydown on input element not firing

Tags: jquery, windows-phone-7, jquery-mobile

I have a javascript to detect keypress events on a specific input on the IOS and Android platform , but it doesnt work in Windows Phone 7.

I have tried keypress ,keydown and keyup and they dont fire at all.

Anyone has a solution?

Comment: Please provide some sample code.

Comment: I think this may be off-topic because the issue is no longer seen as an issue by the author.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the issue was actually IE9 not supporting localStorage, and that affected several portions of the app.
Sorry.
It can be closed.